# How to load data from S3 bucket to Elastic Search in Nodejs Lambda

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want my lambda function (in Nodejs) which will trigger whenever an object is created or updated in amazon S3 bucket and S3 will push the data into elastic search domain.

Can anyone please help me out on this and point me to a code or post that handles this in Nodejs?

Comment: Are you certain that a lambda is appropriate for this? Lambdas have a default timeout of 3s by default (configurable to up to 5 min), so if your import process lasts more than that, you might be in trouble. I'd strongly suggest to look towards Logstash (s3 input, elasticsearch output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) library helps you do all things for adding, edit and search of data into elasticsearch server.

Comment: Just to add on here, I am using AWS Elastic Search service and I need to populate S3 content into AWS Elastic Search domain in Nodejs Lambda.

Comment: in the lambda function use this library, include it in the package.json file so as  result it will be available then the lambda function is called

Comment: thank you, please do upvote it and mark it as correct answer